# What is the market size of high-pressure turbine blades for commercial aircraft?

Tags: commercial-aviation, turbine, blade

I need to calculate the market size for high pressure turbine blades which are used in commercial aircraft. I am working on a business school project on this topic.
Any information which can be used to calculate the total size will be useful:

- Key players and their market size
- Market trends
- Growth
- Latest innovation
- Latest news
- Pricing strategy of these blades by companies
- Merger and acquisitions
- Customer info
- Any key factors to consider

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: GE, P&W, RR, and their joint ventures (CFM, EA) own the designs (intellectual property) and either manufacture them themselves or under an exclusive sourcing agreement. They don't sell individual parts. They sell bundled MRO services to operators with their engines.  Without their cooperation you wouldn't be able to build an approved part and they have no incentive to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Airbus market study http://www.airbus.com/content/dam/corporate-topics/publications/backgrounders/Airbus_Global_Market_Forecast_2017-2036_Growing_Horizons_full_book.pdf gives their estimate of the market over the next 20 years. Boeing does the same thing, their numbers are similar.

2 engines per aircraft, roughly.

Rolls Royce Trent XWB has 68 HPT blades per engine. https://www.rolls-royce.com/products-and-services/civil-aerospace/airlines/trent-xwb.aspx#latest-updates Use that as a guide.

As for cost of blade I don't know, its of the order of thousands of $ per blade